# Go: appending the second item changes the first item

Tags: arrays, json, go, append

Don't know what to say, just look at the code and at the output.
Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Human struct {
    N string `json:"n"`
    C string `json:"c"`
}

func funcname(jDL ...[]byte) {
    jDL_len := len(jDL)
    people := [][]Human{}
    var buf []Human
    var err error
    for i := 0; i < jDL_len; i++ {
        err = json.Unmarshal(jDL[i], &buf)
        fmt.Println("buf", i, buf)
        people = append(people, buf)
        fmt.Println("people", i, people)
    }
    jsoned, err := json.Marshal(people)
    fmt.Println("jsoned", string(jsoned))
    fmt.Println("err", err)
}

func main() {
    i0 := []byte(`[
            {
                "n": "Alice",
                "c": "A1"
            },
            {
                "n": "Bob",
                "c": "A2"
            }
        ]`)
    i1 := []byte(`[
            {
                "n": "Clark",
                "c": "B1"
            },
            {
                "n": "Davis",
                "c": "B2"
            }
        ]`)
    funcname(i0, i1)
}
```

Output:

```
buf 0 [{Alice A1} {Bob A2}]
people 0 [[{Alice A1} {Bob A2}]]
buf 1 [{Clark B1} {Davis B2}]
people 1 [[{Clark B1} {Davis B2}] [{Clark B1} {Davis B2}]]
jsoned [[{"n":"Clark","c":"B1"},{"n":"Davis","c":"B2"}],[{"n":"Clark","c":"B1"},{"n":"Davis","c":"B2"}]]
err <nil>
```

Look at the people 0 and people 1 strings at the output. I'm using *append* to merge buf 0 and buf 1, so the people 1 string in the output should look like this:
`[[{Alice A1} {Bob A2}]] [{Clark B1} {Davis B2}]`, i.e. the first element of the array is changed to the one that is inserted, although it should not be so. What may be a reason and how can I fix it?

I didn't try anything to fix, because I don't see any problems in my code.

Comment: You are reusing buf, so data unmarshaled in first iteration is overwritten by unmarshaling into the same memory in the second iteration. Declare buf inside the loop.

Comment: That has  nothing to do with "appending to the array", but it has to do with your unmarshalling into the and appending very same variable every time. Thus, all the elements in the array are actually pointing to the very same object.

Comment: @mkopriva It helped. TYSM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with others who have commented that the fix is to move the `buf` variable inside of the for-loop, I also believe that the confusion stems from `buf` being a slice and maybe the OP not knowing how slices work. Slices are different from arrays, as described in [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro).

### Slices

The key sentence from the referenced source:

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a **pointer to the array**, the length of the segment, and its capacity.

With this in mind, have a look at the following simplified example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := [][]int{}
    buf := []int{0} // Slice

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        // Modifying the slice which is a pointer to an underlying array.
        buf[0] = i
        // Appending the slice (i.e. pointer).
        slice = append(slice, buf)
    }

    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Ouput: `[[2] [2] [2]]`

This is the behavior that the OP observed in their example. Since a slice is a pointer to an array, `buf` needs to be declared inside the for-loop so that each iteration appends a different instance.

Now let's have a look at what happens if we were to do the same with an array.

### Arrays

The key sentence from the referenced source:

> Go’s arrays are values. An array variable denotes the entire array; it is not a pointer to the first array element (as would be the case in C). This means that when you assign or pass around an array value you will make a copy of its contents.

Now let's look at an example that demonstrates that a copy is made of the array's contents when passing it around (i.e. when passing it to `append`):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := [][1]int{}
    buf := [1]int{} // Array

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        // Modifying the array.
        buf[0] = i
        // Appending a copy of the array.
        slice = append(slice, buf)
    }

    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Output: `[[0] [1] [2]]`

Now all values are different despite the same `buf` variable being used in the for-loop.